# Alarm Declaration giving error UWP App?

Tags: uwp, windows-phone

I got the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error      Error : DEP0700 :
>   Registration of the app failed. AppxManifest.xml(32,10) 0x80080204:
>   The c93686ac-1599-4433-8cfd-8a1d3e588ac8 package cannot register an
>   alarm extension because it does not have the required lock screen
>   capability. (0x80073cf6)  HelloRealWorld

In APPX(Package.appxmanifest) file I have added Alarm Declaration, and can not see Lock Screen Capability to add, I'am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do the following steps:

1. Open the appxmanifest designer, on the application tab, change lock screen notification to "Badge".
2. Switch to Visual Assets tab and select Badge Logo and specify the log image. For test purpose, just simply specify LockScreenLogo.png which is included in the project by default.

Here is the screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Works! Thank you. Any reason behind it?

Comment: It's the normal process for building an alarm windows store app. Same for 8.1 app. check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451440.aspx